# Fundamental Theorem Of Calculus problem: reading a graph

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This question is killing me. I Have a final coming up and need the answer to this.[image]

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $$f(x) = A'(x)$$

At what points does $\quad f(x) = A'(x) = 0\quad$ ?

Comment: Very nice hint +1

Answer (score 0):

Hint: They are the $x$-intecepts.